# Nazi Germany and International Law Before 1945

Tags: nazi-germany, international-law

The fall of the Axis powers accompanied the ['birth'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Court_of_Justice) of the international legal system in its modern form. While the ICJ's predecessor, the [PCIJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_Court_of_International_Justice), was essentially defunct through WW2, there was a considerable period before '39/'40 which suggests more nuance.

From [Hudson's annual review](https://sci-hub.ee/https://doi.org/10.2307/2190290):

> Germany's declaration accepting the Court's obligatory jurisdiction was renewed on March 1, 1933 for a period of five years, and a ratification of the renewed declaration was deposited on July 5, 1933.

> Access to the Court is not dependent on membership in the League of Nations, nor does a withdrawal from the latter affect the Court's jurisdiction in a pending case. Yet a state which has withdrawn from League membership, or which has announced its intention to withdraw, may thereafter be less ready to make use of the Court; following the announcement of Germany's intention to withdraw from the League of Nations, proceedings in two cases pending before the Court were discontinued. A state's withdrawal from the League of Nations does not affect the position of its national as a judge of the Court; fortunately the tenure of the judges is independent.

One of the two pending cases mentioned above is discussed under the section "The Administration of The Prince Von Pless":

> A few days after the announcement of Germany's withdrawal from membership the League of Nations, the Court received a communication from the German Minister at The Hague stating that the German Government did not intend to proceed with this suit.

This is some preliminary (wiki'd) history to prompt a larger question: what was the relationship of (post-'33 Nazi) Germany to international *legal* structures **before** the formation of the ICJ/Nuremberg trials/etc in '45?